# Need fast csv parser for Python to parse 80GB csv file

Tags: python, performance, csv

I am looking for the fastest way to parse an 80GB csv file with 300 columns in Python.

The csv file does not have backquote commas, e.g  `a,"blah,blah,blah",c`

I have tried Python's built-in csv module which gives me ~50MB/s speed.

```
with open(file_name) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        pass
```

With plain `line.split()` I get ~55MB/s:

```
with open(file_name) as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        row = line.split(',')
```

Without parsing, I get ~400MB/s:

```
with open(file_name) as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        pass
```

Using cperf I see that most of time time is used for `split()` or `csv.reader()` or `re.split()`, which I have also used.

Can I make this faster? If a plain read from disk is 400MB/s, I would like to get ~200MB/s while parsing the csv file if possible.

Comment: Perhaps one of the libraries mentioned here could help: [Fastest Python library to read a CSV file](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/)

Comment: You may want to look at http://whitedb.org/ - it has CSV import and it has Python bindings. Whether the import is as fast as the database itself - I don't know, still might be worth a shot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not enough context has been provided, and currently it's a library/algorithm recommendation question. Code Reviews are done over more than just 3 lines of code. Perhaps this should get migrated to StackOverflow instead. Alternatively, Softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, with a library tag.

Comment: I have tried pandas briefly. It has tried to load all to memory but failed with memory error when RAM became short. Not yet tried whitedb.org but they say they try to keep all in RAM. So no option for me.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to create a thread pool and do `line.split()` in separate thread. Playing with thread pool size can give you balance between processing speed and consumed resources.

Comment: There's [the GIL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-gil), though.

Comment: if GIL would have much influence on such task (and I'm not sure it will) then process pool can be used instead

Comment: Have you tried [pypy](http://pypy.org/download.html) ?

Comment: I am using Cython. PyPy would be an option to try. Today I have tried multiprocessing.pool, map_async() but without any performance gain.